# Writing Android Exploits

Tags: android

I want to learn how to detect and write exploits for the Android OS. I am a bit familiar with Linux and have some knowledge in scripting in ruby and python. I had learnt how to write Exploits for basic buffer overflows and SEH. However I am finding very little material for finding and writing Android Exploits. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Found a few presentations by googling. Maybe some of these may help or get you started. Most android devices are ARM based so resources on ARM assembly/ shellcodes may also be useful. Hope it helps some.

[Popping Shell on Android](http://media.blackhat.com/bh-dc-11/Avraham/BlackHat_DC_2011_Avraham-Popping_Android_Devices-Slides.pdf)

[Shellcode on ARM](http://shell-storm.org/blog/Shellcode-On-ARM-Architecture/)

Comment: Thanks for these interesting articles...Is there no definitive guide or documentation available? like for Windows/Linux Exploits

Comment: like @tylerl said at the core Android is a stripped down linux kernel with a different middleware layer. I don't know of a be all end all guide. Looking into ARM assembly and exploits for Linux on ARM should get you headed in the right direction though even though the hardware varies most devices run on ARM. There are projects that are working towards running android on x86 too so that might also be something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Android is just a Linux with a fancy user interface and a custom Java VM. All the same principles and all the same exploits still apply. Most Android exploits are just re-purposed Linux exploits slightly modified to suit the hardware or software found on the phone.